# Вывод связанных таблиц в два DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ms-access

Имеется БД Access из двух связанных таблиц (связь один ко многим; одной строке таблицы1 соответствует несколько строк таблицы2). На форме два датагдида для отображения обоих таблиц БД.
Пытаюсь решить следующую задачу:
Необходимо чтобы при выборе строки датагрида таблицы1 в датагриде таблицы2 отображались только связанные с выделенной строкой данные, т.е. простая выборка.
Пытался сделать как показано [здесь](https://vimore.org/watch/Ykvf8Zl9nr4/datagridview-display-linked-tables-in-two-datagridview/) (т.е. в источник данных таблицы2 поставить связь таблиц), но второй датагрид упрямо показывает всю таблицу2.
Код формы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
namespace v1._0
{
    public partial class Form6DB : Form
    {
        public Form6DB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
 
        private void Form6DB_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.model_ParamTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param);
            nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.DataSource = this.dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param;
            this.name_FirmTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm);
            nameFirmBindingSource.DataSource = this.dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm;
        }
      
        private void buttonSaveMainTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                    nameFirmBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    name_FirmTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm);
                    nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    model_ParamTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param);
                    panel1.Enabled = false;                                              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                nameFirmBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }
 
        private void buttonSaveSecondTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                    nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    model_ParamTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param);
                    nameFirmBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    name_FirmTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm);                
                    panel2.Enabled = false;
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }
 
        private void buttonNewMainTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                panel1.Enabled = true;
                textBoxNameFirm.Focus();                
                dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm.AddName_FirmRow(this.dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm.NewName_FirmRow());
                nameFirmBindingSource.MoveLast();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                nameFirmBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }
 
        private void buttonNewSecondTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                panel2.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.Focus();             dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param.Add_Model_ParamRow(this.dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param.New_Model_ParamRow());
                nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.MoveLast();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }
 
        private void buttonEditMainTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Enabled = true;
            textBoxNameFirm.Focus();            
        }
 
        private void buttonEditSecondTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Focus();            
        }
 
        private void buttonDeleteMainTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    string str;
                    str = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);//захват значения индекса строки из первой таблицы
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == str)
                        {
                            dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm.Rows[i].Delete();
                            model_ParamTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param);
                            name_FirmTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet.Name_Firm);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
 
        private void buttonDeleteSecondTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить запись?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
                model_ParamTableAdapter.Update(dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param);
            }
        }
 
        private void buttonCanselMainTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            panel1.Enabled = false;
            nameFirmBindingSource.CancelEdit();
            nameFirmBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        }
 
        private void buttonCanselSecondTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Enabled = false;
            nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.CancelEdit();
            nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Скрин формы и датагрид1
[image: Скрин формы и датагрид1]
и датагрид2
[image: и датагрид2]

Comment: [Master/detail](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews).

Comment: Данные ссылки мне не помогли, вопрос всё ещё актуален.

Comment: Один `BindingSource` должен указывать на источник данных, второй `BindingSource` должен указывать на _первый_ `BindingSource`.

Comment: nameFirmBindingSource - связан с первой(главной таблицей), modelParamBindingSource - связан со второй таблицей, nameFirmModelParamBindingSource - связь этих таблиц. Все три создались автоматически когда добавилась БД в проект. `nameFirmModelParamBindingSource.DataSource = this.dataBaseMDBDataSet._Model_Param;// проблема в этой строчке?`

Comment: Найденное решение вы можете опубликовать как ответ, а потом и принять его. А для решения новой проблемы задайте _отдельный_ вопрос, нет смысла писать его в комментарии.

Comment: Вообще это легко делается, связь двух таблиц. Добавить на форму объект BindingSource, указать в нем источник данных, а потом в первом гриде в свойствах указать первую таблицу, а во второй - связь между этими таблицами. Я пишу вообще потому что я хочу в третий грид точно также связанные данные отобразить из того, что есть в грид2. Может кто подсказать как это сделать так же без кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один BindingSource должен указывать на источник данных, второй BindingSource должен указывать на первый BindingSource. – Alexander Petrov